# Replace NA values in a R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a column *Total* with about 300 values in a Data Frame,  here first 30 values are NA’s ..  and I would like to fill in these with a vector values c(233,423,545,354,223,646,243,553,634----231),
do you have any suggestions for getting it done?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do:

```
df[1:30, "Total"] <- yourvector
```